# self-decryption paradox in identity based encryption

Tags: provable-security, identity-based-encryption

In the paper [Dual system encryption: realizing fully secure IBE and HIBE under simple assumption](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-03356-8_36) ([free PDF](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-642-03356-8_36.pdf)), the authors said "there is an apparent paradox in this strategy since it seems that the reduction algorithm could simply answer the challenge ciphertext". In the paper [An efficient IBE scheme with tight security reduction in the random oracle model](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10623-015-0035-0), the authors said "Nevertheless, a private key for ID* is not helpful to decrypt challenge ciphertext, which is necessary for solving the  so called self-decryption paradox".

I do not know the meaning of "self-decryption paradox" here. I think there is no restriction for the simulator to both generate the secret key for ID* and the challenge ciphertext for ID*. Thus I do not understand those points in the above papers. Could someone explain it to me?

Comment: In [New chosen-ciphertext secure identity-based encryption with tight security reduction to the bilinear Diffie–Hellman problem](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ins.2015.07.011), J. H. Park, K. Lee and D. H. Lee give more explanations on what that call the "self-decryption paradox". I'm not quite getting it, thus will abstain from answering.